# React Native state management (Redux, Context API or Graphql)

Tags: react-native, redux, graphql

After I got into the basics of React Native and developed some components, I did some research on how state management is being organised in larger apps and am trying to find out what I should be focusing on to learn those days. At first it seemed to be obvious to me that I would be using Redux, but it seems a lot of people are happy using GraphQL in a way that makes Redux even obsolete after implementing it. Now there's also the Context API and I'm wondering what you would be choosing today when writing an entire new React Native app that would be interacting with 3rd pty APIs a lot.

Thanks and regards,
Dennis

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on a lot of different factors. There are some cases where choosing one over the other makes more sense, but ultimately the decision is up to you. Nevertheless, let's look at some scenarios where it might make sense to use each of these options.

**Redux**

Redux is best suited for applications that need complex state management and a single source of truth. Typically you would wrap your entire application in a Redux provider so that the state of your entire application changes when this store changes. So this is best used when you have state that is used in many different places throughout the app and needs to be available to every component. An example might be that of a game where a player's actions impact everything around them. Here you could dispatch actions to Redux when a player takes damage or levels up to increase enemy difficulty.

**Context**

Context is (in my opinion) simpler to use than Redux and is useful for sharing state between a group of components. This is not necessarily for the entire app, although it can be and would effectively be a simpler replacement for Redux in that case. Rather, Context is used in situations where you have deeply nested components that need state from a parent several layers up, or for components that aren't nested within eachother but need the same data in order to work together. An example of when to use context would be in designing an image editor. You could have an image component wrapped in a filter component wrapped in a crop component wrapped in a sizing component and not want to pass the props down to each level every time. So you would wrap the top most layer in a provider and have each nested component be a consumer. You could also have a toolbar that can change the sizing, filter, etc. and so they would also be consumers and would call functions passed in by the provider. The rest of your app would have its own state and would not change when this state changes.

**GraphQL**

This is useful if you need to pull in state from several differnt APIs or backend services and combine this state all at once. This is dependent on either fetching from a preexisting GraphQL API or by setting up your own to pull in data from your other endpoints. Since you said you would be interacting with a lot of different 3rd party APIs, you could set up an Apollo server to retreive data from them, or use a service like AWS AppSync with Lambda if you want a managed GraphQL service. The beauty of GraphQL lies in that you can query for only exactly what your application needs at any given time. So instead of the APIs dictating what data the client can access, it is the client that tells the APIs what it wants, and then GraphQL gets it in an efficient manner. A perfect fit for this style of state management would be a blogging application. Here you need to pull in information on an author, and get all of their posts, and get all of the comments on their posts, and get their user info, and then get how many followers they have, etc. Where each of these pieces of data would normally be served from their own REST endpoint, you would end up making dozens - and in some case hundreds - of requests to your APIs and pulling in a huge amount of unnecessary data. With GraphQL you can declare what you want in the shape that you want it and pull it into your app in a single request. This would save you a lot of trouble in trying to see if your APIs have all returned a certain piece of data yet or not, and so you don't have to write a thousand if/else statements in your components. Only one would be necessary. However, GraphQL tends to be much harder (in my opinion) to setup compared to using Redux and Context. So be prepared that there is a tradeoff here. When people switch from Redux to GraphQL, they usually switch to the Apollo library in order to make use of their local state management and cache systems. These are not technically a part of GraphQL but are rather just nice add-ons that Apollo provides.

So that's just a general overview of the strengths and weaknesses of using each option. Again, which one (or which combination) you end up using really is dependent on your app's requirements. My suggestion is to experiment and find out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I found the following package that seems to be solving the purpose of global state in the Context API: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hooks-global-state

Comment: Glad to help. Hope you make some great apps

Comment: This talk seems to be reflecting my question as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUMMUyQtMSg